# Is there a binary operation $\otimes:\mathbf N^2\to\mathbf N$ such that $n\otimes n=0$ and $0\otimes n=n\otimes 0=n$ other than xor?

Tags: abstract-algebra, arithmetic

Is there an associative binary operation $\otimes:\mathbf N^2\to\mathbf N$ such that $0\otimes n=n\otimes 0=n$ and $n\otimes n=0$ other than xor?

Basically I am trying to find something that is simpler than xor (which needs to compute the binary representation of a number) but with the same properties.

For example $(m,n)\mapsto m-n$ would work if it was associative.

**Edit.** @Mastrem proved in a comment that such an operation is always commutative.

Comment: If I've got this right,
$$
a\otimes b = a\otimes 0\otimes b = a\otimes (a\otimes b)\otimes (a\otimes b)\otimes b=0\otimes b\otimes a\otimes 0 = 0\otimes b\otimes a,
$$
so any such operation must be 'almost commutative'.

Comment: Yep I think you are correct. I wonder if I should ask for $0\otimes n=n$ too (if not already implied) so that the operation has to be commutative.

Comment: Probably not what you're looking for but $n \otimes 0 = n = 0 \otimes n$ and $n \otimes m = 0$ otherwise works

Comment: @HallaSurvivor A solution without branching would be more elegant but I must admit that it works…

Comment: If we know all the outputs of some operation, then it is uniquely determined, though perhaps there are varying _formulas_ or _algorithms_...

Comment: @paulgarrett In the question, there is no output specified for $n\otimes m$ when $n\neq 0$, $m\neq 0$ and $m\neq n$. Otherwise it would give us a formula for xor with only addition, too good to be true

Comment: Ah, ok, wasn't paying enough attention! :)

Comment: The latest edit of the requirements seems to be incorrect, it repeats $n\otimes 0=n$ twice and leaves out the value of $n\otimes n$ altogether.

Comment: @PeterKošinár Oops, the title was the correct statement

Comment: It seems like for any permutation $\sigma$ of $\mathbb{N}$ fixing 0, $(m, n) \mapsto \sigma^{-1}(\sigma(m) \oplus \sigma(n))$ should work, but most non-identity permutations will not preserve xors.

Comment: @DanielSchepler I am not sure to understand your comment, what function are your defining in terms of the operator $\otimes$ that I want to define?

Comment: I'm defining $m \otimes n := \sigma^{-1}(\sigma(m) \oplus \sigma(n))$ where $\oplus$ is the xor operation.

Comment: In fact, I think my example gives all the possibilities: with the given conditions (including associativity), $(\mathbb{N}, \otimes)$ extends canonically to an $\mathbb{F}_2$-vector space structure with $\otimes$ as addition.  Being a countably infinite $\mathbb{F}_2$-vector space implies that it must have dimension $\aleph_0$, so it is isomorphic to $(\mathbb{N}, \oplus)$.  If $\sigma : (\mathbb{N}, \otimes) \to (\mathbb{N}, \oplus)$ is such an isomorphism, then you must have $m \otimes n = \sigma^{-1}(\sigma(m) \oplus \sigma(n))$.

Comment: That's interesting, I am not sure to understand why $\sigma$ has to be bijective but I'll think about it